# Update a field in PostgreSQL and generate an event from that to be caught in a Java Application

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I'm developing an app about a vote section and need your help.
This voting system has a table called Section to control the vote sections (obviously).
The table has some fields but 3 are important for this case: Start_date, duration, and status.
The start_date is defined when creating the section as long as its duration.
The status is setted based on the start_date and duration: Here's the list of possible status:
1: WAITING_TO_START: When the actual date is before the start_date
2: IN_PROGRESS: When the actual date is AFTER the start_date and BEFORE (start_date + duration).
3: FINISHED: When the actual date is AFTER the start_date and AFTER (start_date + duration).

All said, here's the problem:
I have no idea how to automatically update the status on postgresSQL for when the now date gets after the start_date and shot an event to my Spring app that would notify the clients.

Any help would be awesome.

Here's my table section and column definitions:
[image]

Here's my section MODEL and REPOSITORY, respectively

```
package com.testdbserver.desafiovotacao.data.models;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.testdbserver.desafiovotacao.data.enums.SectionStatusEnum;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.FutureOrPresent;
import lombok.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name="section")
public class Section {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="pauta_id")
    private Pauta pauta;

    @Column(name="status", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private SectionStatusEnum status;

    @Column(name="created_at", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdAt;

    @FutureOrPresent
    @Column(name="dt_start", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dtStart;

    @Column(name="duration", nullable = false)
    private int duration;

    @JsonBackReference
    public Pauta getPauta() {
        return pauta;
    }
}
```

```
package com.testdbserver.desafiovotacao.data.repositories;

import com.testdbserver.desafiovotacao.data.models.Section;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public interface SectionRepository extends JpaRepository<Section, UUID> {
    @Query(value = " SELECT s FROM Section s " +
            "         WHERE (:allowFinishedSections=false and s.status <> 'FINISHED') " +
            "           AND s.dt_start < :maxDate " +
            "         ORDER BY s.dt_start asc", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Section> getAllSections(boolean allowFinishedSections, Date maxDate);
}
```

Here's my POM.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.testdbserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>desafio-votacao</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>desafio-votacao</name>
    <description>Challenge project to create a vote system to a credit cooperative</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved similar problems and here is my solution
I used **Scheduling Tasks**

After it automatically runs the function of you